# In JavaScript Classes, can a child call its super parent methods by default?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

With a simple Child class that extends a Parent class and both of them define the same method:

```
class Parent {
  method() {
    console.log('Parent method');
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  method() {
    // super.method()
    console.log('Child method');
  }
}

const child = new Child();
child.method();
```

Can the Child not override the method by default and instead have both methods fired (without needing to manually invoke the super method?)

Answer (score 2):

No, you must invoke the super method. There is no OO language that I know of that allows a super method to be automatically invoked along with the derived version. If you think about it, it is the correct thing to do as sometimes you would want the super's version as well, and sometimes you would not.